# How to pass function that returns value to prop of component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a function that returns true or false based on a parameter and the prop takes a bool. It is not working. Thank you for your help.

```
  const myfunction = (input) => {
    if (input == 0)
       {
          return true
        }
         else if (input == 1)
        {
         return false

         }
       }
    


<Component myprop={()=>{myfunction(input)}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to use return before the myFunction call.

try:

`<Component myprop={()=>{return myfunction(input)}} />`

But this is not a great idea to do in react because you will recalculate all the time. You can do something like this:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
   const myprop = useMemo(() => {
    if (props.input == 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (input == 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }, [props.input]);
  return <Component myprop={myprop} />;
}
```

This way you will avoid having to recalculate every time the component rerenders and rerender the Component since it's props didn't change.

Comment: Adding return did not work. I am creating an arraying of components and then mapping it out. I am not sure if that makes a different

Comment: My function is never executed. It always does what it does as if it is set to true.

Comment: The problem about what you are doing is that you are passing a function as a prop and not the result of the function, that's why I'm showing how to do using the useMemo to calculate the value of the function.